# Copy data from one workbook to last line of another

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code to work with two sheet. would copy the data fine but then I went to change the name, to the actual sheets I would be using and it sopped working. Both workbooks are open, and will be open while working with them.

```
Sub copypasteover()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, LR As Long
Set wb2 = Workbooks("TS-141260 Data Dump C312H ABC Tester.xls")
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
LR = wb2.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wb1.Worksheets("Data Origin").Range("A36:c36").Copy Destination:=wb2.Worksheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & LR + 1)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

It will stop on this part:

```
LR = wb2.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The code is intended to copy certain range from one workbook and paste that into the last free row of another.

I have tried changing the name a bit, in the code, on the sheets, on the workbooks, but it keep having the error. Does it have anything to do with how long the second workbook name is or how its spaced out?

Workbook one: copy-paste.xlsm
Sheet in workbook one: Data Origin (button that runs the script)

Workbook two: TS-141260 Data Dump C312H ABC Tester.xls
Sheet in workbook two: Data Dump

Why does it keep stopping there and how can I fix it so it will work?
Thank you.

Comment: `It will stop on this part` doesn't help much..What error do you see?

Comment: run-time error '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error. Is the error I receive

Comment: try `LR = wb2.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & wb2.Sheets("Data Dump").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
`

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your second workbook has `xls` extension: `"...Tester.xls"`. But `xls` workbooks has only 65536 rows, while `xlsx/xlsm` - 1048576 rows.

In `Range("B" & Rows.Count)` part `Rows.Count` refers to active sheet and it seems that active sheet belongs to `ThisWorkbook` which has 1048576 rows. So use this one instead:

```
With wb2.Sheets("Data Dump")
   LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: If i replace LR = wb2.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row with what you have here it errors. But the one you had above it does does. Maybe I am not certain how to use this newer one.

Comment: Also, how could I edit this to start at B17 and go down and not start at B1? Thank you for your help

Comment: 1) have you used it exactly as I use: with `With` statement? 2) use `LR = Application.Max(17,.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

Answer (score 0):

Use Cells instead of Range:

```
LR = wb2.Sheets("Data Dump").Cells(Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Row
```